# Root Mean Square (rms) function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

So I'm calculating basic statistics in my worksheet and it includes code such as:

xxx = Application.worksheetfunction.**average**(etc etc etc

yyy = Application.worksheetfunction.**min**(etc etc etc

zzz = Application.worksheetfunction.**max**(etc etc etc

My question: Is there an RMS equivalent function where I can simply plug it in place of where I have 'average, min, max' functions in that code? And if there isn't then what would be the most efficient means to code in to find RMS solutions?

I hope I've stated the goal clearly enough. I'm curious as to whether or not there is a predefined RMS function for VBA or whether or not I've got to create some sort of user defined function? ~ That of which I'm fairly new to as well so if there isn't a simple line of code to write for this, I'll have to do more reading on UDF's.

**EDIT:**

I've got around 30,000 rows, and for simplicity's sake: imagine two columns. Column A has the year i.e. 1941 or anything else through 2008. Column B is a numeric value. I'm just trying to put code together that gives decade summaries of Average, Min, Max, and the RMS values.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean my "min" and "max" in relation to RMS?

Comment: This information is helpful, however I'm looping through multiple decades through multitudes of different years. Rather than manually scroll through and define ranges I've got it in VBA to automate it; and it allows me to use the 'SumSq' and 'CountA' functions in VBA. However the only option VBE recommends is a 'SqrtPi' function rather than simply a 'Sqrt'. I'm most certainly lacking knowledge on the subject, but if you could perhaps nudge me a bit farther in the right direction of the 'sqrt' that would be most helpful!

Comment: Absolutely, I've got around 30,000 rows, and for simplicity's sake: imagine two columns. Column A has the year i.e. 1941 or anything else through 2008. Column B is a numeric value. I'm just trying to put code together that gives decade summaries of Average, Min, Max, and the RMS values.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand.  You never stated in the original question that you wanted individual RMS values.  So in my electrical world I would just multiply by SQRT(2) to get RMS values, then take the average and determine the mins and maxes, but I'm thinking you want something different.

Comment: @pnuts , Yes, in this smaller situation a PivotTable would work nicely; however this is a pretty small part of the entire project I'm working on. I was just missing the correct VBA grammar to add in this chunk. However I do appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the average with

```
=SQRT(SUMSQ(A:A)/COUNTA(range))
```

or in VBA:

```
r = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumSq(Range("A:A")) / Range("A:A").Count) ^ (1 / 2)
```

Comment: This information is helpful, however I'm looping through multiple decades through multitudes of different years. Rather than manually scroll through and define ranges I've got it in VBA to automate it; and it allows me to use the 'SumSq' and 'CountA' functions in VBA. However the only option VBE recommends is a 'SqrtPi' function rather than simply a 'Sqrt'. 

I'm most certainly lacking knowledge on the subject, but if you could perhaps nudge me a bit farther in the right direction of the 'sqrt' that would be most helpful!

Comment: @WATERflowTech, ok, I added a VBA function also, you'll probably want to use named ranges.

Comment: That's it, good call on the to the nth power. I hadn't thought of that but will without a doubt remember that in the future! Thanks Lance!

Answer (score 0):

A VBA function that accepts arrays (any rank) and ranges with multiple areas (a discontinuous range like A4:B6,C11:D15), or even a union of ranges in a formula. It skips non number datatypes (including dates, boolean, blanks etc).

You can use it in VBA code, or as a UDF in a worksheet formula such as:

"=RMS(A1:A10)" (basic usage)

"=RMS(A1:A10,C1:C10)" (multiple ranges (or arrays for that matter))

"{=RMS({1,2,3,4})}" (array formula entered with Ctrl+shift+enter)

```
Function RMS(ParamArray args()) As Double

    Dim arg, arr, area As Range, ss As Double, n As Long

    For Each arg In args
        If TypeOf arg Is Range Then
            For Each area In arg.Areas
                arr = area.value
                If VarType(arr) < vbArray Then
                    queryRmsElements Array(arr), ss, n
                Else
                    queryRmsElements arr, ss, n
                End If
            Next area
        ElseIf VarType(arg) > vbArray Then
            queryRmsElements arg, ss, n
        Else
            Err.Raise 1, "RMS", "Invalid Argument"
        End If
    Next arg

    RMS = (ss / n) ^ 0.5

End Function
Private Sub queryRmsElements(ByRef elements, ByRef ss As Double, ByRef n As Long)
    Static element As Variant
    'Enumerate to cover rank > 1 (vs. Iterate)
    For Each element In elements
        Select Case VarType(element)
            Case VbVarType.vbByte, _
                 VbVarType.vbCurrency, _
                 VbVarType.vbDecimal, _
                 VbVarType.vbDouble, _
                 VbVarType.vbInteger, _
                 VbVarType.vbLong, _
                 VbVarType.vbSingle
                 ss = element ^ 2 + ss
                 n = n + 1
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next element
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
Function RMS(Intervalo As Range)

Dim SomaQ As Double
Dim Tamanho As Integer

SomaQ = 0
Tamanho = Intervalo.Count
SomaQ = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumSq(Intervalo)
RMS = Sqr(SomaQ / Tamanho)

End Function
```